# How to navigate to another component after subscription has finished?

Tags: angular, rxjs, es6-promise, angular-router, rxjs-subscriptions

I am sending a GET/POST request and wait for the response. After I get the response I would like to navigate to the "patients" page from dashboard page:

```
this.api.getData(body).subscribe((res) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/patients']);
});
```

However, I get the following error when router.navigate() is executed:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: control._registerOnCollectionChange is not a function at cleanUpControl (forms.mjs:1614:17)
at FormControlDirective.ngOnDestroy (forms.mjs:5143:13)
at executeOnDestroys (core.mjs:7357:1)
at cleanUpView (core.mjs:7260:1)
at destroyViewTree (core.mjs:7093:1)
at destroyLView (core.mjs:7238:1)
at RootViewRef.destroy (core.mjs:21238:1)
at ComponentRef.destroy (core.mjs:21640:1)
at RouterOutlet.deactivate (router.mjs:2504:28)
at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRouteAndOutlet (router.mjs:2098:28)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:1)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:1)
at zone.js:1278:1
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25535:1)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:1)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491:1)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1661:1)
```

These are the routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'patients', pathMatch: 'full', component: PatientsListComponent }
];
```

This is the parent component:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="main-container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Couldn't find anything about the error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are probably using a FormBuilder in your PatientsListComponent, which results in the given error.

Comment: The patientListComponent is empty, just a new component so I don't use FormBuilder.

Comment: Try to debug it on the subscription first, like console.log in the subscription, before trying to navigate as a side effect of your subscription. If everything is good, then and only then you can proceed to navigation. Oh and by the way, don't forget to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be related to formcontrol which is not relevant to any of your routes or the code related to navigation. Look at the formcontrol usage in your component

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I had a FormControl defined as follows:

```
control = new FormControl()
```

I subscribed to it without having a FormGroup. To resolve the issue, I created a FormGroup:

```
form = this.fb.group({
control: new FormControl(''),
});
```

Using forms in this manner resolved the problem. I couldn't find any answers or posts online addressing this issue, so I'm providing this solution.